# TensorFlow.js DeepLab Model Shape Mismatch Error

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am working on a project where I am using TensorFlow.js and the DeepLab model for background removal in browser applications. However, I am encountering a shape mismatch error that I can't seem to resolve.

When attempting to execute the DeepLab model, I receive the following error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The shape of dict['ImageTensor'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [1,-1,-1,3], but was [1,1,1,513,3]
```

- I am using TensorFlow.js version 2.8.5.
- I have loaded the DeepLab
  model using @tensorflow-models/deeplab
  Here's the relevant part of my code:

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as deeplab from '@tensorflow-models/deeplab';

export default async function rembg(imageUrl) {
  const model = await deeplab.load();
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = imageUrl;
  await img.decode();

  // Resize the input image to match the model's input size
  const targetHeight = 513;
  const targetWidth = 513;

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = targetWidth;
  canvas.height = targetHeight;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight);

  // Preprocess the image
  const inputTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(canvas);
  const inputTensorNormalized = inputTensor.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(127.5)).sub(tf.scalar(1));

  // Add batch dimension to the input tensor
  const inputWithBatch = inputTensorNormalized.expandDims(0);

  // Perform background removal
  const segmentation = await model.segment(inputWithBatch);
  const backgroundMask = segmentation.segmentationMap;
  const foregroundMask = backgroundMask.notEqual(0); 
  const maskedImage = inputTensorNormalized.mul(foregroundMask);

  // Convert the resulting image to base64
  const base64Image = tf.browser.toPixels(maskedImage)
    .then(async (pixels) => {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.width = targetWidth;
      canvas.height = targetHeight;
      const imageData = new ImageData(pixels, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    });

  return base64Image;
}
```

The error seems to indicate a shape mismatch in the input tensor provided to the DeepLab model. I have attempted to reshape and preprocess the input image, but I'm still facing this issue.

I expect the code to successfully remove the background from the provided image and return the processed image.

What I've Tried:

Reshaping and resizing the input tensor to match the model's requirements.
Normalizing the input tensor.
Adding a batch dimension to the input tensor.
Reviewing the documentation and online resources, but I haven't found a solution that works.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights on how to resolve this shape mismatch error and successfully use the DeepLab model for background removal in TensorFlow.js.

Thank you in advance for your help!